# scipy.optimize.minimize() in place of gradient desc

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, gradient-descent

Given a set of points we'd like to find a straight line fitting the data best possible. I have implemented a version where the minimization of the cost function is done via gradient descent, and now I'd like to use the algorithm from scipy (`scipy.optimize.minimize`).

I tried this:

```
def gradDescVect(X, y, theta, alpha, iters):
    m = shape(X)[0]
    grad = copy(theta)

    for c in range(0, iters):
        error_sum = hypo(X, grad) - y
        error_sum = X.T.dot(error_sum)
        grad -= (alpha/m)*error_sum

    return grad

def computeCostScipy(theta, X, y):
    """Compute cost, vectorized version"""
    m    = len(y)
    term = hypo(X, theta) - y
    print((term.T.dot(term) / (2 * m))[0, 0])
    return (term.T.dot(term) / (2 * m))[0, 0]

def findMinTheta( theta, X, y):
        result = scipy.optimize.minimize( computeCostScipy, theta, args=(X, y),  method='BFGS', options={"maxiter":5000, "disp":True} )
        return result.x, result.fun
```

This actually works pretty fine and gives results very close results to the original grad desc version.
The only problem seems that `fminunc()` stops execution before reaching minimum value of `costFunction()`.
its sure that `costFunction()` works fine, and no. of iteration of `minimize()` is set greater than max iters it takes.

Output:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
     Current function value: 15.024985
     Iterations: 2
     Function evaluations: 16
     Gradient evaluations: 4
Cost : 15.0249848024
Thteta : [ 0.15232531  0.93072285]
```

while the correct results are :

```
Cost : 4.48338825659
Theta : [[-3.63029144]
 [ 1.16636235]]
```

See how close the results are: 
[image: why is'nt minimize() continuing decreasing the cost function]

Comment: You may want to give us the gradient as well.

Comment: @cel i just edited the post to include gradient but how could it affect the results, as minimize() only takes the function (costfunc()) to be minimized.

Comment: I do not get it. Why are you talking about `fminunc()` ? This is a Matlab function. If you want to fit noisy data like that you may want to check out PyMC: http://twiecki.github.io/blog/2013/08/27/bayesian-glms-2/ . My favorite is lmfit http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/

Comment: You sure SciPy isn't giving you a local minimum? If you want global optimization, try something like [`scipy.optimize.basinhopping`](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html#scipy.optimize.basinhopping).

Comment: actually i had a bug in my code (one of the matrix dimensions had to be adjusted), after that i have tried several scipy optimization algos,.. all return same correct results seems like they all do give global min. thanks though for your reply @ user2357112, you replied exactly what i was looking for,.. :)